# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer - Eclipse Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following error when trying to run Java project:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package jdk.internal.jrtfs in both module java.base and module jrt.fs
```

I tried to remove JDK and JRE and install them again, but the problem is still there.

Could someone explain how to solve this issue?

Could system restore help?

Comment: do you have many jdk installatin ?

Comment: @Issam EL-GUERCH, Just one, 10.0.2

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: When you add external .jar file to new user library make sure to check "System boot class path".

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today and I tried "Run as -> Java Application". Then it was fixed. (btw, the jdk I used was jdk-11.0.2)
Hope you would find this helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you have a run configuration with no project and main class configured. You can fix this by going to your run configurations and deleting the empty configuration or choosing the correct one when running it.

Answer (score 1):

In the run configuration mention the Project and the name of the main class. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue, I think it's something to do with the newer version of Java.

When creating a new java project [heres a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl9Jk.png)

click version 1.8 and then save it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If your program works on command line, the problem is not the JDK installations but the IDE which is Eclipse. try reinstalling the Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seems that the dependencies on the `Modulepath` got mixed up.
A rebuild of the project after deleting the `Launch Configuration` file of the project under
`…\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches` and deleting the `bin` directory fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clean project then create a new configuration where you indicate the file that contains the main method in your project the run the project again

Answer (score 0):

Using [Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers],
[Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)].

This resolved it for me:  [delete module-info.java] from Project.

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes in project when many main() available in your  Spring boot  project try to remove others or run this as separate java application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was an additional folder in the src/main/resources directory, that had the same package-folder name than the mentioned module.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you just have to delete the current package, and under project, you can simply create that class dont create any package just create one class under, and then it works fine.